# Angular compile error in visual studio code

Tags: angular

> error TS2339: Property 'appSettings' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; apiKey: string; authDomain: string; databaseURL: string; projectId: string; storageBucket: string; messagingSenderId: string; appId: string; measurementId: string; }'.

```
constructor( private store: Store<IAppState>,
             private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
             private router: Router,
             private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) {
    this.layouts = LAYOUTS;
    this.defaultSettings = environment.appSettings;
```

Comment: Good you mentioned the error! But please also post your question and the code as [example].

Comment: Please help me to solve this

Comment: constructor(
    private store: Store<IAppState>,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.layouts = LAYOUTS;
    this.defaultSettings = environment.appSettings;

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Type doesn't support the properties you are trying to access.  In your error it shows the following...

```
{ production: boolean; apiKey: string; authDomain: string; databaseURL: string; projectId: string; storageBucket: string; messagingSenderId: string; appId: string; measurementId: string; }
```

There is no appSettings property there, yet you are trying to access environment.appSettings.

Either you are trying to access appSettings from the wrong item, or you need to add your appSettings to your environment.ts.